# Python Program gets hung up on certain numbers

Tags: python

I made a program that divides two numbers and then returns the answer in decimal form.  It works for all the numbers I have tested except 8 and 9 and any combination of the two.  Any sort of explanation as to why this happens is welcome.

```
cont = True
while(cont):
    initChoice = 0
    print " "
    print "What would you like to do?"
    print "1) Divide two numbers"
    print "2) Find the GCD of two numbers"
    print "3) Find the LCM of two numbers"
    print "0) Exit"
    initChoice = input("")
    if(initChoice == 1):
        #This hangs up when certain numbers are entered
        #It only seems to hang up when only 8 or 9 are involved
        #For example (8,9) (9,8) (88,89) (89,88) (98,99) (99,98)
        #It gets hung up on num1 = num1-num2
        num1 = raw_input("Please enter the first number: ")
        num2 = raw_input("Please enter the second number: ")
        num1 = float(num1)
        num2 = float(num2)
        numer = num1
        denom = num2
        ans = 0.0
        iter1 = 0.0
        iter2 = 0.0
        while(num1 > 0):
            if(num1 >= num2):
                num1 = num1-num2
                iter1 += 1
            else:
                num2 = num2*0.1
                ans += iter1*(10**(-iter2))
                iter1 = 0
                iter2 += 1      
        ans += iter1*(10**(-iter2))
        print numer,"divided by",denom,"is",and
```

And yes I know that as is it would run indefinitely, I have more code that can end the loop.

Comment: It would run indefinitely and it's hanging; are you ending the loop in all cases? `print "something"` in the loop and see if it does stop.

Comment: I already said I know this part alone runs indefinitely, I did not post the entire code just the part causing the issue.  I have it run until the user chooses zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "while(num1 > 0)" is definitely the problem. It has to be with the precision of the float poin variables on computers. From python you could find it importing sys as follows:

```
sys.float_info.min
```

Therefore, your code may be like the one below in order to avoid infinite loop.

```
from sys import float_info

cont = True
while(cont):
    initChoice = 0
    print " "
    print "What would you like to do?"
    print "1) Divide two numbers"
    print "2) Find the GCD of two numbers"
    print "3) Find the LCM of two numbers"
    print "0) Exit"
    initChoice = input("")
    if(initChoice == 1):
        #This hangs up when certain numbers are entered
        #It only seems to hang up when only 8 or 9 are involved
        #For example (8,9) (9,8) (88,89) (89,88) (98,99) (99,98)
        #It gets hung up on num1 = num1-num2
        num1 = raw_input("Please enter the first number: ")
        num2 = raw_input("Please enter the second number: ")
        num1 = float(num1)
        num2 = float(num2)
        numer = num1
        denom = num2
        ans = 0.0
        iter1 = 0.0
        iter2 = 0.0

        precision=float_info.min

        while(num1 > 0+precision):
            if(num1 >= num2):
                num1 = num1-num2
                iter1 += 1
            else:
                num2 = num2*(0.1)
                ans += iter1*(10**(-iter2))
                iter1 = 0
                iter2 += 1
        ans += iter1*(10**(-iter2))
        print numer,"divided by",denom,"is",ans

    elif(initChoice == 0):
        break
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. I didn't even think to consider this option.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Change the while loop  condition to check for num2 being zero as like "while(num1 > 0 and num2 > 0):". That should work.

Comment: num2 should never technically reach zero as it is only being modified by *0.1 each time num2 > num1.